# Understanding giving up Lock within wait()

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, operating-system

From the Java [Condition Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html)

```
class BoundedBuffer<E> {
   final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
   final Condition notFull  = lock.newCondition(); 
   final Condition notEmpty = lock.newCondition(); 

   final Object[] items = new Object[100];
   int putptr, takeptr, count;

   public void put(E x) throws InterruptedException {
     lock.lock();
     try {
       while (count == items.length)
         notFull.await();
       items[putptr] = x;
       if (++putptr == items.length) putptr = 0;
       ++count;
       notEmpty.signal();
     } finally {
       lock.unlock();
     }
   }

   public E take() throws InterruptedException {
     lock.lock();
     try {
       while (count == 0)
         notEmpty.await();
       E x = (E) items[takeptr];
       if (++takeptr == items.length) takeptr = 0;
       --count;
       notFull.signal();
       return x;
     } finally {
       lock.unlock();
     }
   }
 }
```

Suppose a thread `Produce` calls `put` and so `Produce` is now owning the lock `lock`. But the `while` condition is true so `Produce` does `notFull.await()`. My question is now if a thread `Consume` calls `take`, at the line which says `lock.lock()` what exactly happens?

I am kind of confused because we let the old `lock` go in the critical section and now need to acquire it from a different thread.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Await and signal() inside locks java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52227460/await-and-signal-inside-locks-java)

Answer (score 1):

If you look closer at the Javadoc for [Condition.await()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html#await()), you'll see that the await() method atomically releases the lock and suspends itself:

"The lock associated with this Condition is atomically released and the current thread becomes disabled for thread scheduling purposes and lies dormant until one of four things happens..."